# Не работает pdfviewer

Tags: android, kotlin, pdf

При создании разметки(в .xml)библиотеки **barteksc:android-pdf-viewer**, вылезает ошибка *Inspection 'Unresolvable tag' options*

> В build библиотеку поключил
> (implementation 'com.github.barteksc:android-pdf-viewer:3.2.0-beta.1')
> , ошибок не было

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Добавьте jcenter() в файл android/build.gradle

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        jcenter()
    }
}
```

Comment: Интересно бы узнать подробности, чему это помогает.